# NDSolve with boundary conditions at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, symbolic, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have a feeling that similar questions have been asked before, but here goes.

I'm trying to solve an ODE using `NDSolve`, with boundary conditions for one of the variables set to $\pm \infty$.

To be concrete,

```
NDSolve[{D[(1 + z^2)*D[f[z, s], z], z] == (1 + z^2)^(-3)*s*
f[z, s], f[-100, s] == 1,f[100, s] == 1}, f, {z, -100, 100}, {s, 0, 5}]
```

The parameter that I am setting equal to $100$, is what I would like to move to $\infty$. Any helpful suggestions as to how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: `Maple 2018.2` can solve this PDE analytically. Solution by `HeunC` function. MMA does not have this function.

Comment: Mathematica solves the general problem `DSolve [{D[(1 + z^2)*D[f[z, s], z], z] == (1 + z^2)^(-3)*s*f[z, s]}, f, {z, s}]` analytical. The solution includes `DifferentialRootObjects` . Perhaps you can adapt the boundary conditions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5):

As observed by [Ulrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53677/ulrich-neumann) above, `DSolve` provides a solution in terms of `DifferentialRoot`.  `DSolve`does not, however, handle large `z` boundary conditions well for this problem, so we need to help it.  First, observe that the ODE and its desired boundary conditions are symmetric about `z == 0`.  So, the derivative of `f` at `z == 0` should vanish.  The value of `f` itself is unknown at `z == 0`, but can be set to an arbitrary value, say `1`, after which the value of `f` at large `z` can be computed, and the ODE solution normalized by that quantity to obtain `f == 1` at large `z`, because the ODE is linear and homogeneous.  Thus, for `s == 3` (for instance),

```
ss = DSolveValue[{D[(1 + z^2)*D[f[z, s], z], z] == (1 + z^2)^(-3)*s* f[z, s]}, 
    f, {z, s}] /. {C[1][s] -> 1, C[2][s] -> 0};

norm = N[ss[10^10, 3]]
Plot[Evaluate[ss[z, 3]/norm], {z, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {z, f}, LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 14}]

(* 3.58427 *)
```

[image]

Incidentally, the ODE also could be solved using `NDSolve` with the same boundary conditions at `z == 0` and normalization based on the computed value at large `z`.  Probably, the approach given above is more efficient.

Comment: What a straightforward solution, thanks. You could improve your solution idea by defining `norm[s_] := ss[10^10, s] // N` . Doing so the solution of the pde is `ss[z, s]/no[s]`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @bbgodfrey answer the solution of the pde can be calculated as follows:

```
ss = DSolveValue[{D[(1 + z^2)*D[f[z, s], z], z] == (1 + z^2)^(-3)*s*f[z, s]}, f, {z, s}] /. {C[1][s] -> 1, C[2][s] -> 0};

norm[s_] := N[ss[10^10, s]] (* s dependend norm! *)
Plot3D[ss[z, s]/norm[s] // Evaluate, {z, -10, 10}, {s, 0, 5},PlotRange -> {0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice plot.  When I reproduce it with version 11.3, though, I first receive four error messages.  What is your experience?

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Thanks. In MMA 11.0.1 it works without errormessages. Perhaps in 11.3. you have to put `//N`around the plot argument?

Comment: @ bbgodfrey Sorry I don't know why, but  message window doesn't pop up. In my version  I also get the message `DifferentialRoot::ifprec: Parameters in DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY],\[FormalX]},{-s \[FormalY][<<1>>]+2 \[FormalX] Power[<<2>>] (<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]+Power[<<2>>] (<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]==0,\[FormalY][0]==1,(\[FormalY]^\[Prime])[0]==0}]] are not exact numbers.`