# DifferentialRoot with parameters that "are not exact numbers"

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

In the course of developing an [answer to 185859](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/185883/1063), I encountered the following difficulty.  With

```
ss = DSolveValue[{D[(1 + z^2)*D[f[z, s], z], z] == (1 + z^2)^(-3)*s* f[z, s]}, 
    f, {z, s}] /. {C[1][s] -> 1, C[2][s] -> 0};
```

the command

```
FindRoot[ss[5, s] == 3, {s, 3}]
```

produces two error messages,

> > DifferentialRoot::ieqn: The supplied equation in ... is not a linear differential equation with polynomial coefficients.
> >
> > DifferentialRoot::ifprec: Parameters in ... are not exact numbers.

but nonetheless gives what appears to be the correct answer.

```
(* {s -> 2.83293} *)
```

However, if I attempt to substitute this result into `ss`,

```
N[ss[5, s] /. %]
```

I obtain these errors again but `DifferentialRoot` returns unevaluated.  I would have expected `3.` as the result.

My question is, since `DifferentialRoot` accepts parameters that "are not exact numbers" when used with `FindRoot` (or `Plot`, for that matter), how do I convince it to accept not-exact numbers more generally?

Comment: Too hard for Mathematica. It will be easier to use ` F = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[(1 + z^2)*D[f[z], z], z] == (1 + z^2)^(-3)*
     s*f[z], f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, f, {z, -10, 10}, {s}]; FindRoot[F[s][5] == 3, {s, 3}]
Out[]= {s -> 2.83293}  F[2.832929841106108][5] Out[]= 3.`

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I do not think it is too hard for Mathematica, because `DifferentialRoot` evaluates correctly when called from `FindRoot`, just not when called directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Block[{obj, z1, s1},
 obj[z0_?NumericQ, s0_?NumericQ] := N[
   {z1, s1} = SetPrecision[{z0, s0}, Infinity]; ss[z1, s1],
   Precision@{z0, s0}];
 sol = FindRoot[obj[5, s] == 3, {s, 3}]
 ]
(*  {s -> 2.83293}  *)
```

It takes about two minutes.
With this approach, you can use the `WorkingPrecision` option and `obj` adjusts the precision automatically.

Comment: This is very clever, although I need to think more about it.  Note that I want to be able to substitute `sol` back into `ss` without errors.  It appears that this can be done by replacing the second to the last line of your answer by `{sol = FindRoot[obj[5, s] == 3, {s, 3}], tst = obj[5, s] /. sol}`, which returns `{{s -> 2.83293}, 3.}`.  Thanks.